# Why is overflow property coming in the way of background color?

Tags: html, css, overflow

The following is my code (HTML and CSS).

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>

ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
background-color: green;
}

ul.topnav li {
float:left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

With the code as above the background color doesn't appear. Whereas when I add an overflow property to the style and make it hidden, it magically appears. It makes me doubt my understanding of the overflow property. Can someone explain what is happening and what exactly is the overflow property?

Comment: I checked it and found not useful. The other question is about margins getting the color altered depending on overflow property. My question is about the background color disappearing without a hidden overflow property